# How to create a console app in Enterprise edition

Tags: console, enterprise

On the [documentation page](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=console2_define_app.htm&language=en_US) of "Create a console app", the following line is present

> "Salesforce console Available in: Enterprise and Unlimited Editions
>   with the Sales Cloud for an extra cost"

My question is; where can I purchase a possibility to create console apps?

Answer (score 0):

You should contact your account executive to discuss getting the right license in order to get access to the Salesforce Console, as it will depend on if you've currently got a Sales Cloud vs. Service Cloud license.

If you aren't sure who your AE is you can call or use the live chat from Salesforce.com and a support agent should be able to help you get that information.

You can find more information about various editions and feature licensing here http://www.salesforce.com/crm/editions-pricing.jsp